# ROS Human-Robot mapping (Baxter)

Tags: ros, virtual-reality, robotics

I'm having some difficulties understanding the concept of teleoperation in ROS so hoping someone can clear some things up.

I am trying to control a Baxter robot (in simulation) using a HTC Vive device. I have a node (publisher) which successfully extracts PoseStamped data (containing pose data in reference to the lighthouse base stations) from the controllers and publishes this on separate topics for right and left controllers.

So now I wish to create the subscribers which receive the pose data from controllers and converts it to a pose for the robot. What I'm confused about is the mapping... after reading documentation regarding Baxter and robotics transformation, I don't really understand how to map human poses to Baxter.

I know I need to use IK services which essentially calculate the co-ordinates required to achieve a pose (given the desired location of the end effector). But it isn't as simple as just plugging in the PoseStamped data from the node publishing controller data to the ik_service right?

Like a human and robot anatomy is quite different so I'm not sure if I'm missing a vital step in this.

Seeing other people's example codes of trying to do the same thing, I see that some people have created a 'base'/'human' pose which hard codes co-ordinates for the limbs to mimic a human. Is this essentially what I need?

Sorry if my question is quite broad but I've been having trouble finding an explanation that I understand... Any insight is very much appreciated!

Comment: If you can render a common reference frame for both the data coming from your VR setup and the real robot, then whatever poses you get from VR can be sent for control on the robot via an appropriate transformation. This assumes you have a task space controller for the robot. Then you can totally avoid any configuration mapping between humans and Baxter because it all operates in a common operational (task) space.

Answer (score 1):

You might find my former student's work on [motion mapping using a kinect sensor with a pr2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zZtOlOuqEdw&index=24&list=LLMmUzvvz7M1JUoho1NzrRiA) informative.  It shows two methods:

1. Direct joint angle mapping  (eg if the human has the arm in a right angle then the robot should also have the arm in a right angle).
2. An IK method that controls the robot's end effector based on the human's hand position.

> I know I need to use IK services which essentially calculate the
>   co-ordinates required to achieve a pose (given the desired location of
>   the end effector). But it isn't as simple as just plugging in the
>   PoseStamped data from the node publishing controller data to the
>   ik_service right?

Yes, indeed, this is a fairly involved process!  In both cases, we took advantage of the kinects api to access the human's joint angle values and the position of the hand.  You can read about how Microsoft research implemented the human skeleton tracking algorithm here:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/real-time-human-pose-recognition-in-parts-from-a-single-depth-image/?from=http%3A%2F%2Fresearch.microsoft.com%2Fapps%2Fpubs%2F%3Fid%3D145347

I am not familiar with the Vive device. You should see if it offers a similar api for accessing skeleton tracking information since reverse engineering Microsoft's algorithm will be challenging.

Comment: Ah thank you for the info anyways. So with the pr2 robot, you had to do some kind of configuration with the co-ordinates and such? I read somewhere that for the Oculus Rift, the co-ordinate system had to be altered to match that of Baxter robot.  Something like xBaxter= -zOculus, yBaxter=xOculus, zBaxter= yOculus. This is for the point co-ordinates anyways.  Is this process similar to that of your pr2?

Comment: "Something like xBaxter= -zOculus, yBaxter=xOculus, zBaxter= yOculus." -  That sounds like a standard rotation is being applied.    I'm not sure I completely understand your question, but yes there is a rigid transformation frame attached to the camera that was not in the same orientation as the base link of the pr2 robot so we had to transform it into the desired one.   I recommend using rviz- select the option to view the tf coordinate frames.  See here for info:  http://wiki.ros.org/tf

Comment: Ah okay so it's to do with transformations- sorry I'm still new to all of these concepts. Thanks very much for the tip in rviz and the link.  So can I please just to double check with you as you've been helpful?  To teleoperate a robot, I need to: first publish pose data from the controller device, retrieve this data, apply transformations to get the correct co-ordinate frame and then finally use the ikservice to determine where the end-effector pose should be.  Am I missing any stages in between?

Comment: I am assuming the vive device gives you a position of your hand and the camera is in the wrong orientation compared to the robot.    If so, then this pose is provided in the camera's reference frame.  Then you should transform the pose from the camera's reference frame to the robot's reference frame by multiplying it by the correct transformation matrix (possibly rotation only if you just care about orientation). Finally, command the robot to go to this position using a Cartesian controller OR use ikservice to determine the joint angle to achieve this position and send joint angle command